# Change Chrome or Web Gmail swipe actions in iPhone/iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, gmail

In Chrome browser in iPhone, when I open gmail website and open an email and then swipe left/right then it navigates to the previous/next email. How do I remove this swipe action in Chrome or in Web Gmail settings when using iPhone/iOS?

Comment: What kind of research have you already done on this?

Comment: @nohillside: I searched in Google but did not find a solution. Checked in iOS setings -> Chrome -> but could find any option to modify the swipe gestures(Probably because I want to change gmail website and not all Chrome swipe gestures). Opened web Gmail in iOS Chrome browser->Settings gear icon->Not able to find anything related to swipe gestures

Comment: It is about the use of Apple products so it‘s on-topic here. If you don‘t get an answer within a few days, please flag for mod attention and we can migrate it to webapps.